# Phone numbers are read with special characters in swift IOS when voice over is on

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have these dynamic accessibility text coming down from server and it could be as below.

Dial: 1-800-425-9456
Dial: 425-295-2958

On the client I am setting this to button controls accessibility Text.
However, when voice over reads phone number with country code, it is reading the last hypen for 1-800-425-9456 (1 800 425 hypen 9456)

When it reads phone number without country code like 425-295-2958 , it just reads as 425 295 2958.

I want to make sure when a string containing phone number is read, the special characters like  (),- etc within the phone numbers are not read. IOS contacts app does not read special characters except the + that prefixes country code some times.

The code I have is

```
button.accessibiityLabel = serverString
```

Any pointers on what more to do to avoid reading special characters within the phone number.

Comment: Just manipulate the accessibiityLabel string to your needs

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't try to force a screen reader to announce things a certain way.  I was able to replicate your problem in iOS Voiceover.  I hadn't noticed it before.  The last hyphen is indeed spoken in the first example, although Voiceover says "minus" instead of "hyphen" for me.  The second example doesn't announce the hyphen.  I added a '+' in front of the country code but that still causes the last hyphen to be announced.

The user has some control over this.  They can go into Settings > Accessibility > Voiceover > Verbosity > Numbers and change the pronunciation from "Words" to "Numbers".  That causes all the digits **and** all the punctuation to be read, which is the opposite of what you want.  **All** the hyphens are announced.

[image]

Alternatively, if you can post-process the phone number and remove all the punctuation and change them to blanks, then you can set the accessibility label to "1 800 425 9456" but still display "1-800-425-9456".